# How to unpublish an android app only from a single country?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an android app and i want to unpublish the app from a single country and make it available to all other countries . Is it possible in playstore?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using `Google Play Console Beta`, Navigate to your `app > launch > production`. Then move to `Countries/Regions` tab. Now click on Remove countries/ regions to get pop having list of all available countries.

[image: Remove Countries]

Answer (score 4):

go to production and select countries/region remove or add

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You only need to  do the next

Select the country to disable or enable

Link about the steps

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en

Steps

To manage your app's availability:

> Go to your Play Console. Select an app. Select Store presence >
> Pricing & distribution. In the "Countries" section, select Manage
> countries. Update your app's country selection. If you add a country
> for a paid app, new prices are automatically added. If needed, you can
> then edit local prices. Submit your app update. Note: For details on
> how to target a staged rollout to specific countries, go to release
> app updates with staged rollouts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i unselect the country i want to remove and gave an update, will the earlier version still be available in that country?

Answer (score 0):

In the google play console, go to Store presence -> pricing & distribution.
Click on manage countries and you can make your app unavailable in the desired country and submit an update.

Comment: Will the earlier version still be available in that country ?

Comment: When the app is unpublished, the app is removed from the play store from that country. So, the app will not be available in that country. The users who installed before you unpublished will not be affected, but your updates to the app won't be available in that particular country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select your application.
3. Select "Presence in Google Play Store" > "Price and distribution".
4. In the section "Countries", select "manage countries" and in these section select only the country you want.

Names of sections may be different because I have the console in Spanish.

I hope it helps you, regards

Comment: What will happen to the earlier version? Will it be still available in that country that i removed?

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to update the current version for a single country, but you can upload a new version and delete the existing one. Regards